# Can you help me understand the construction of this sentence?

Tags: sentence, construction

Can you help me identify the individual components of this sentence, please?

> Asking askers asking askers asking.

I realise the second occurrence of `asking` is a verb, however, I am unclear on the names of the other parts. I believe that the first occurrence of `asking` is an adjective and I suppose that the first occurrence of `askers` is a noun but, given that some of these words are the subject of a verb and some are subjective to the verb (if I have the correct terminology?) I would not be surprised if there are other better ways to describe the sentence parts.

Suggested expansion: The asking askers are asking the askers who are asking.

I suppose that those being asked have earlier asked and are now themselves being asked.

Comment: There are several ways to parse this phrase, but it doesn't seem to be a complete sentence because it is missing a verb to go with any subject you pick (_askers_ or _asking askers_).

Comment: @oerkelens Thank you for looking at it. I will add a bit more of my understanding to the question in case it helps solicit better understanding.

Comment: I think that, ultimately, it has something to do with buffalo.

Comment: I wonder if there's an obscure verb sense of "asker". Wiktionary has it as a Danish verb. "askers" would then be the third-person singular conjugation.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem to be a complete sentence, as it's missing a verb. It sounds more like a complex noun phrase, with several pronouns elided. It can be interpreted as:

> (Asking askers) [who are] asking (askers [who are] asking)

Structurally it's similar to:

> Working doctors treating patients suffering